# Union of 4 tables with same column types (but different data) order by max time in AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, iot, amazon-athena

I'm having an issue I have 4 tables that look like this:

| device | volume1 | volume2 | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| device_id | x | y | time_devicemessage |

Each table is for one single **device** so I have 4 devices, which send messages in different timestamps.

I would like to know a query for how to unite these 4 tables into 1 but showing only the last **volume** data from each table based on its timestamp.

So it may look like this:

| device | volume1 | volume2 | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| deviceA | lastvalue (x) | lastvalue (y) | time_devicemessageA |
| deviceB | lastvalue (x) | lastvalue (y) | time_devicemessageB |
| deviceC | lastvalue (x) | lastvalue (y) | time_devicemessageC |
| deviceD | lastvalue (x) | lastvalue (y) | time_devicemessageD |

Thank you very much for your support, I would appreciate lots the help!

Regards, Ruben.

Comment: What did you try so far? Please, check this: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: A more scalable solution (more than 4 devices) can use the concept of partition (device=deviceA,...) to create a single table that you can then simply query with group by device and get max(time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the last row of each table and then UNION these four rows, something like this:

```
SELECT device, volume1, volume2, time FROM device1 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1

UNION 

SELECT device, volume1, volume2, time FROM device2 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1

UNION 

SELECT device, volume1, volume2, time FROM device3 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1

UNION 

SELECT device, volume1, volume2, time FROM device4 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the syntax you want is:

```
(SELECT device, volume1, volume2, time
 FROM device1
 ORDER BY time DESC
 LIMIT 1
) UNION ALL
(SELECT device, volume1, volume2, time
 FROM device2
 ORDER BY time DESC
 LIMIT 1
) UNION ALL
(SELECT device, volume1, volume2, time
 FROM device3
 ORDER BY time DESC
 LIMIT 1
) UNION ALL
(SELECT device, volume1, volume2, time
 FROM device4
 ORDER BY time DESC
 LIMIT 1
);
```

Note that storing similar information in four different tables is considered a bad data design.  It is better for all the data to go into one table.